# Permitting certain values in a 2d array

Tags: java, eclipse, multidimensional-array, integer

I am trying to initialize a global 2d array called square that consists of ints. The variable square may only contain values -1 through 8. I thought it was something like the code shows below but eclipse is giving me a syntax error. Is there any possible way to do this?

```
private final int [][] square;
```

to

```
private final [-1..8] [][] square;
```

Comment: that's not how you declare an array.

Comment: I edited the original post to what I had previously to what I am trying to do. Hopefully that clarifies the issue.

Comment: It's not possible. Use data hiding and validation to ensure only valid values can be input.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is some form of validation when entering values into the array. You will also require some form of access to the array if you are going to set it as `private`, so you can use `public` getters and setters as shown below:

```
private final int [][] square = new int[10][5]; //Initialize square 2D array here.

public int getSquareValue(int x, int y)
{
    return square[x][y];
}

public void setSquareValue(int x, int y, int value)
{
    //If the value is between -1 and 8, set square[x][y] as that value. If not, then return an error message.
    if (value >= -1 && value <= 8)
    {
        square[x][y] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Input value is not between -1 and 8");
    }
}
```